# How do in-built methods do things?

Tags: methods

Just something that has been playing on my mind recently. A java example of what I mean by an inbuilt method: `System.out.println("hi");`. How does this method actually make 'hi' appear on screen? I can imagine a long series of methods inside methods inside methods, but how would the 'base' method do what it is supposed to?

Comment: I've been wondering this too, and I would add the question: How can this be so much faster than own written functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a good example for println. http://luckytoilet.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/how-system-out-println-really-works/

Essentially, the call gets processed through the call stack, until it reaches native code, then you're into OS specific code, i.e. the windows API.